# Как отключать звуки в программе в момент звонка?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как отключать звуки в программе в момент звонка?

Answer (score 0):

На Ваш вопрос невероятно сложно дать ответ, учитывая, что: 
1. Обращение с аудио в Android — тёмный практически незадокументированный лес 
2. Непонятно, каким образом Вы выводите звук.